# Algorithm design: can you provide a solution to the multiple knapsack problem?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am looking for a pseudo-code solution to what is effectively the [Multiple Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems) (optimisation statement is halfway down the page). I *think* this problem is NP Complete so the solution doesn't need to be optimal, rather if it is fairly efficient and easily implemented that would be good.

The problem is this:

- I have many work items, with each taking a different (but fixed and known) amount of time to complete.
- I need to divide these work items into groups so as to have the smallest number of groups (ideally), with each group of work items taking no longer than a given total threshold - say 1 hour.

I am flexible about the threshold - it doesnt need to be rigidly applied, though should be close. My idea was to allocate work items into bins where each bin represents 90% of the threshold, 80%, 70% and so on. I could then match items that take 90% to those that take 10%, and so on.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Did you try reading the PDF linked from the Wikipedia page? http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/pisinger/95-1.pdf (PDF)

Comment: yeah I did, I have trouble making sense of statements like  1w e  ñ e  ð  ðñ | y  e ðñ ò ñ e ð ó

Comment: ok, that didnt work, but you get the idea

Answer (score 11):

You need http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/knapsack.html,  chapter 6.6 "Multiple knapscack problem - Approximate algorithms". There is pseudo-code (Pascal style) in the text and Fortran implementations (yes, it's an old book) as a ZIP file.

Comment: +1 thank you very much for the link BTW both Martello and Toth were my professors at Uni!!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the problem is NP complete (Wikipedia [confirms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)), so there's probably not much sense in attempting to solve it exactly.
However, any number of approaches might be *good enough* for you: greedy, genetic algorithms, simulate annealing...greedy is probably the easiest to implement:

```
while (time available in block greater than smallest task duration)
  find the longest fitting task
  add it
```

...you get the idea.

Comment: I have the following problem - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415617. Are there any greedy approaches for that?