# Python split large file with condition max row and customer to be only in one file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .xlsx file with 1.2mil rows. I need to split into small files with max. 10k rows. The second condition is that each file must contain different customers. Two files can't contain invoices from the same customer.

Row Customer Invoice
9998 Customer A Invoice1
9999 Customer A Invoice2
10000 Customer A Invoice3
10001 Customer B Invoice 1
The limit is max 10 000 rows in a file therefore "Customer A" should be in the following file because 3rd invoice is over the limit. Customers can't be divided into two files. How do you calculate the row limit?

My code divides the large file into small files with a row number limit.

```
# slsx file name to be read in
for file in Path(os.path.join(root_path, month_folder)).glob('*.xlsx'):
    in_xlsx = file
        
    # get the number of lines of the csv file to be read
    number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(in_xlsx, encoding="iso-8859-1")))
       
    # size of rows of data to write to the file,
    rowsize = 10000
    header = ['Zmluva','UcOk','SU','Odb.miesto','ZmluvnuUcet','ObchodnyPartner','ZacZucObd','Kon.zuc.ob','C.zuct.dokl','Tlac.dokl','DrZuct','FaktPosSluz','FaktObl','OdpJedn','SU','TypTarify','Tarifa','Sk.faktov', 'EIC','Mesiac']
        
    # start looping through data writting it to a new file for each set
    for i in range(0, number_lines, rowsize):

        df = pd.read_excel(
            in_xlsx, 
            nrows = rowsize, # number of rows to read at each loop
            skiprows = i # skip rows that have been read
            )

        df.columns = header # add headers to created files
        
        file_name = os.path.basename(file)
        name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]

        # xlsx to write data to a new file with indexed name. input_1.xlsx etc.
        out_xlsx =  str(name) + str('_') + str(i) + '.xlsx'
        path_to = os.path.join(root_path, url)
        output_dir = path_to + '\\' + out_xlsx

        df.drop_duplicates(keep='first').to_excel(
            output_dir,
            index = False,
            header = True,
            # mode = 'a', # append data to xlsx file
            # chunksize = rowsize # size of data to append for each loop
        )
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to use a [Knapsack algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) to find the ideal combinations of customers

Comment: Also [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392284/algorithm-design-can-you-provide-a-solution-to-the-multiple-knapsack-problem)

Comment: what if a customer occupies 22_000 rows, would you throw away the remaining 12000 records?

Comment: The customer will not have more than 30 rows. Most cases will have 10 rows. We cancel invoices for periods 01-10/23.

Comment: If really customers have up to 20 row, I wouldn't bother trying to find the optimal combination, just create a new file whenever the next customer would cause the creation of a new file

Comment: I was thinking about creating a helper table with the number of documents in a given file for each customer. Through the loop, I checked how many documents to add, and whether the addition would not exceed the limit. If so, it creates a new file and I continue adding to the new file, and so on.